# Split date ranges into details by months using pandas or numpy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a list of events (A, B, C) in a dataframe and two dates for each event and I need to split those dates within their respective months.

*Example:*

```
data = {'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Start_time': ['2017-12-15', '2017-12-15', '2017-12-15'], 'End_time': ['2018-01-17', '2017-12-22', '2018-05-22']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

| Events | Start_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2017-12-15 | 2018-01-17 |
| B | 2017-12-15 | 2017-12-22 |
| C | 2017-12-15 | 2018-05-22 |

*Expected results:*

| Events | Start_date | End_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2017-12-15 | 2017-12-31 |
| A | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-17 |
| B | 2017-12-15 | 2017-12-22 |
| C | 2017-12-15 | 2017-12-31 |
| C | 2018-01-01 | 2018-01-31 |
| C | 2018-02-01 | 2018-02-28 |
| C | 2018-03-01 | 2018-03-31 |
| C | 2018-04-01 | 2018-04-30 |
| C | 2018-05-01 | 2018-05-22 |

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). For us to help you, provide a minimal reproducible problem set containing sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. What you have provided falls short of this goal. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Comment: you will have to write own function for this.

Comment: in duplicated answer I found intenresting `pd.date_range('2017-12-15', '2018-01-17', freq="M')` which gives missing `2017-12-31`, and if you add `timedelta(days=1)` then you should get also missing `2018-01-01`. And similar way you can do with longer ranges.

Comment: @furas thanks for sharing, the solution is similar to what I am looking for...